# jquery add class to closest parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form, and some the fields are set inside 3 groups of collapsible divs, I wan't after the validation that if any field has errors the parent div receive a class to unfold it.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="fields_panel">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div id="basic_info_fields" class="panel-collapse collapse in"> <!-- add class "in" -->>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="col-md-12 m-b-0">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-line error"> <!-- if this div has "error" -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have two more panels with the same structure, eacho one with a couple of fields, I'm trying to find if any `form-line` has `error` and append to the `panel-collapse` parent the class `in` to unfold it.

Right now I have the following jquery code:

```
$(function () {
    var elem = $('.panel').find('.form-line');
    if (elem.hasClass('error')) {
        elem.closest('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
    };
});
```

But it apply the `in` class to all `panel-collapse`.
What should I do to apply it only to the top level parent that have a child element with that class, and not to all parents?

Comment: elem.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.panel-collapse').addClass('in'); (maybe too much parent(). try removing some if dont work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `hasClass` won't work as `elem` is an array of jQuery objects - not just one.

Why do you need it - why not just include the class in your selector:

```
$('.panel').find('.form-line.error').closest('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
```

This also stops you looping through elements in the array that doesn't have the class thus improving efficiency

Comment: Thanks you solution works perfectly, to be honest I'm trying to learn jquery and sometimes I just have no clue what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code:

```
$('.panel').find('.form-line.error').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
});
```

`$(this)` refers to the specified element which has the `error` class.

Comment: @Pete It was a minor simplification of the code... It produces the exact same output.

Comment: @Pete I upvoted both answers, but I still prefer this one as it removes ambiguity for the reader. `.closest()` returns a single element. However, if you call it on a jQuery collection, it returns a collection. That is internal knowledge that the reader has to know in advance. Which, by the way, is exactly what was tripping up the OP...  Using `.each()` implies immediately to the reader that there may be one or more results returned, and they want to do something for each result.

Comment: @Pete As for copy and pasting someone's answer to change something as minor as I did is just downright unethical. If I had made any drastic changes, I 100% agree with you - but to jump down my throat for the edit I made is completely uncalled for.

Comment: @Pete Undoing my edit, calling me out in the comments, and lecturing me about protocol. Lol